# how to combine multiple select statement and limit for each of them

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union, window-functions

column `cat` has three different values - `lorem`, `ipsum` and `dolor`
need to select `15 rows` from each category (`cat`) i.e. `45 rows total`
tried with `union` - without success
any help?

```
select id, title from arts where cat = 'lorem' order by ind asc limit 15
union
select id, title from arts where cat = 'ipsum' order by ind asc limit 15
union
select id, title from arts where cat = 'dolor' order by ind asc limit 15
```

Comment: Do you have the same behavior if you wrap each query in brackets? `(SELECT...LIMIT 15) UNION  (SELECT...LIMIT 15) UNION (SELECT...LIMIT 15)`

Comment: @EdmCoff, it works, thanks a lot, will you write the answer?

Comment: I've added my answer with a link to the documentation.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The required syntax is to wrap the individual limit queries in brackets like the following

```
(select id, title from arts where cat = 'lorem' order by ind asc limit 15)
union
(select id, title from arts where cat = 'ipsum' order by ind asc limit 15)
union
(select id, title from arts where cat = 'dolor' order by ind asc limit 15)
```

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html#union-order-by-limit):

> To apply an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to an individual SELECT [in a
> union], parenthesize the SELECT and place the clause inside the
> parentheses...

Answer (score 2):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this with window functions:

```
select id, title
from (
    select a.*, row_number() over(partition by cat order by ind) rn
    from arts a
    where cat in ('lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor')
) t
order by cat, ind
```

You control the order in which rows are returned with the outer `order by`: this orders rows by category, then by `ind`.

This should be more efficient than `union all`, since the table is scanned only once.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to order by id? If so...

You should do

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
   (SELECT id, title from arts where cat = 'lorem' ORDER BY id LIMIT 15)
   UNION ALL
   (SELECT id, title from arts where cat = 'ipsum' ORDER BY id LIMIT 15)
   UNION ALL
   (SELECT id, title from arts where cat = 'dolor' ORDER BY id LIMIT 15)
) AS result;
```